# How to determine if a row took place during a defined episode

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has people and date when an event occurred:

```
Person   DateOfEvent
1        1/1/2014
1        1/20/2014
1        9/17/2014
2        1/1/2014
2        3/3/2014
2        6/30/2014
3        4/10/2014
3        4/22/2014
```

I need to be able to sort these rows into episodes for lack of a better term. The first occurrence of an event will start an episode which lasts for 30 days from the initial occurrence. Any date within 30 days should be considered part of that episode and would not start the count again. If a row has a date that is not within 30 days of an initial occurrence, it begins a new episode.

I was picturing something like this:

```
Person  Date        Episode
1       1/1/2014    1
1       1/20/2014   1
1       9/17/2014   2
2       1/1/2014    1
2       3/3/2014    2
2       6/30/2014   3
3       4/10/2014   1
3       4/22/2014   1
```

What's the best way to do this in T-SQL (preferably without cursor)?

Comment: The Datediff/dateadd functions may be usefull to you

Comment: Hold on.. Not hard. Let me work on this a bit

Comment: My mind is a bit fuzzy about this, but I feel like there might be an elegant solution using window functions (perhaps `DENSE_RANK`).

Comment: Yeah I was looking at Window functions but I couldn't figure out how to get it to partition the right way. I didn't look at DENSE_RANK but I'll look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, unfortunately, is an iterative problem.  You can solve it using recursive CTEs, but they will not be super fast.

The following approach starts at the first value for each person and then assigns the episodes one-by-one based on your logic.

```
with data as (
      select person, date, row_number() over (partition by person order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ),
     cte as (
      select person, date, seqnum, 1 as episode, date as episodestart
      from data
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select data.person, data.date, data.seqnum,
             (case when datediff(day, cte.episodestart, data.date) < 30 then cte.episode
                   else cte.episode + 1
              end) as episode,
             (case when datediff(day, cte.episodestart, data.date) < 30 then cte.episodestart
                   else data.date
              end) as episodestart                 
      from cte join
           data
           on data.person = cte.person and data.seqnum - 1 = cte.seqnum
    )
select person, date, episode
from cte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9c80/2) is a SQL Fiddle showing the results.

Comment: results don't match the requirements

Comment: @Bulat . . . It returns the results the OP wants and meets the requirements set forth in the question, so I'm not sure what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I copied your code to sqlfiddle and it did not. now it does in sqlfiddle link. +1 for that )

Comment: Nice Gordon.. I'll give you +1 for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have a lot of time.. I think you can use a windowing function with a lag statement. basically, if you're unfamiliar with lag and windowing functions you can compare the record set as the query optimizer processes the rows. So combining the LAG statement with an order by, you can get the date difference from the last row in the logical result set (order by person, event) and apply logic based on the results.

The below is just a really simple example (not enough time in the train ride to type it all out). If I were to do this in real life, I would try and add a counter/ROW_NUMBER to another outer select statement and partition it by the person/event to get the correct episode number.

Here is the working proof of concept: I can try and elaborate tomorrow if needed.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
 [person] INT
,[dateOfEvent] DATE)

INSERT INTO #Temp ([person], [dateOfEvent])
VALUES(
'1',        '1/1/2014'),
('1',        '1/20/2014'),
('1',        '9/17/2014'),
('2',        '1/1/2014'),
('2',        '3/3/2014'),
('2',        '6/30/2014'),
('3',        '4/10/2014'),
('3',        '4/22/2014')

SELECT * ,
    [episode] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,dateOfEvent,ISNULL(LAG(dateOfEvent,1) OVER (ORDER BY person,dateofEvent),dateOfEvent)) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #Temp
    ) as X

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

This was a good challenge. :)

Comment: Had to change it to:`SELECT * ,
    [episode] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,ISNULL(LAG(dateOfEvent,1) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY person,dateofEvent),dateOfEvent),dateOfEvent) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FROM #Temp` to get the episode to work right for proof of concept. What were you thinking to iterate through EpisodeIDs (Say if there are three episodes for one person or if you add ('2','7/01/2014') into the table)? Definitely see where you were going with it though.